# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError background

Tags: java, android, out-of-memory

This is one,

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ders.raydingoz.com.dersprogram/ders.raydingoz.com.dersprogram.aksamyemek}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class <unknown>
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2305)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:161)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1265)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class <unknown>
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:626)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:675)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:700)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:470)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:359)
at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2015)
at ders.raydingoz.com.dersprogram.aksamyemek.onCreate(aksamyemek.java:38)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5431)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600)
... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:677)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:507)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:872)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3056)
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3694)
at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3624)
at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:474)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:236)
... 26 more
```

and one more;

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 111384 byte allocation with 24040 free bytes and 23KB until OOM
at java.nio.charset.Charsets.toUtf8Bytes(Native Method)
at java.lang.String.getBytes(String.java:775)
at java.lang.String.getBytes(String.java:759)
at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromium.loadDataWithBaseURL(WebViewChromium.java:664)
at android.webkit.WebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(WebView.java:940)
at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.s.g.loadDataWithBaseURL(SourceFile:328)
at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.o.m.run(SourceFile:57)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5834)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1388)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1183)
```

i get this report from google plays, Applications running smoothly on my own phone, and others. But S4 and S5 devices have reported. Background images already 100KB. Debug did not show any problem. I think I need to reduce the memory used. is not it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a excellent example of "What to avoid when writing a question on StackOverflow".

If you're developping an app, and you need to allocate large memory heaps, you need to add in the manifest, under the tag application :

> android:largeHeap="true"

Comment: if you look at my profile. You've seen that the first question. I saw the solution for you here before. and going to apply, thanks. But could not the meaning of the error report.

Comment: Ok, start by asking a question and then give the error stack. In your case it would be better if you give also some code because it's not clear at all what the problem is.

Comment: The problem was not that. already using 20 MB cache in total. Background, I save as nodp. Thank you.

Comment: My string size is 14MB json file. When I try to convert it to string this error occurs... And i added this line, but facing same error... can u help me to resolve it... Error is  "Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:354)
at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:228)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841) ". Thanks in advance